# Swift model class error handling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I have come with below approach for Model class initialisation with error handling. But whenever make init method as throwable in swift, I am not able to access from Obj C code. Declaration doesn't get create in `projectname-Swift.h` header file. Without "throws" it works perfect.

```
 init?(dictionary: NSDictionary?)throws {

        if let dictionary = dictionary {
             // Parsing   

        }
        else {
            throw MyError.DictionaryNil("Nil Dictionary")
        }
    }
```

Am I missing anything here? My model class is subclass of `NSObject` and it has only one init method.

Comment: Maybe you need to put @objc over your class declaration?

Answer (score 2):

Well nullable & throwing isn't supported. You can remove `?` and it will give you an error parameter.

Also you can't overload a throwing init as failable.
So it leaves you with the one with error parameter. Maybe you can call that from a convenience initializer in objective-c to send a `nil` `error` parameter.

Comment: This is technically correct. `init?` and `throws` together doesn't make sense. Either you use `nil` for reporting errors or you throw an error. If you use both, it cannot be correctly exported to Obj-C error parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll want to use this with Objective C, I think you'll have to resort to the lowest common denominator in error handling: an `NSError` parameter.

Comment: Note: Not the ideal solution, but it'll work for sure. Perhaps others will know better tricks.

Comment: That's exactly what `throws` means in Swift. It's a special syntax for error parameters.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? I'm aware `NSError` params are automatically transformed to `throws` for Swift's consumption. But I'm not sure if Swift `throws` is implmented with `NSError` params, but I strongly suspect it isn't.

Comment: I am afraid I did not explain myself well. If you declare a method with `throws` in Swift, it will get imported to Obj-C as a method with an error parameter. The problem here is that in Obj-C you don't check success of a function/method by checking the error parameter, you always have to check the return value. `init?` basically means that `nil` is a valid return value, therefore `nil` cannot be used by Obj-C to check for errors. And that's the problem. `init?` and `throws` together in Swift doesn't make sense and cannot be exported correctly to Obj-C.

Comment: Oh I see, nice explanation. I didn't know that conversion worked from swift to objc